# Sqlite - Different queries, different speeds?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I'm writing a C++ program based on a sqlite database. 
I have a table `table1` with various fields. There are many functions that need to read every columns of `table1`:

```
select * from table1 where (condition);
```

The result of the query is stored in a suitable memory structure.

Other functions requires only the first field of `table1`:

```
select field1 from table1 where (condition);
```

I can obtain the values of `field1` by executing the first query and reading only the first field in the memory structure that holds it, or I can implement a function that calls the second query.
Should I do this in order to improve the performance of my program?

Comment: To me, it is more about "intent" than "performance." If I need only "field1" then I would only pick that up, rather than picking everything up and then silently discarding them. Also, in this approach, this specific query is more resilient to any schema change in future.

Comment: While it may not matter for a local database, a query pulling back data over a network could pull significantly more data using `*` instead of the desired field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the second query not even primarily because of performance concerns, but because it more clearly indicates the *purpose* of your code. As soon as you query all fields and then throw all but one away someone will start debugging the code and wonder why all the other fields are unused.

Orthogonally I would like to note that programmatically using `select *` is just *asking* for problems when the table schema changes sometime down the line. I would highly recommend explicitly spelling out the columns you need, even if that list is "all currently available columns".

Comment: Many thanks. I normally specify the name of all columns, I wrote `*` just for the sake of simplicity.